# Microsoft cognitive service Recognize Text api

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services

I call the  microsoft recognize text api by passing the image that I had taken from my phone, there no error occur but every time the api will return me empty string as result doesn't matter what image I post . I try those image with the microsoft ocr api and it return me result, can anyone help ?

Comment: Hi Wei, Can you post the code through which you post the image to azure and get back response?

Answer (score 0):

> I call the microsoft recognize text api by passing the image that I had taken from my phone, there no error occur but every time the api will return me empty string as result doesn't matter what image I post.

In [documentation of Recognize Text API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/587f2c6a154055056008f200), we can find:

> *The service has accepted the request and will start processing later.*
>
> *It will return Accepted immediately and include an “Operation-Location” header. Client side should further query the operation status using the URL specified in this header.*

I suspect that you directly get/extract content from the response after you made a request to recognize text, so the content would be string.Empty.

To [get recognize text operation result](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/587f2cf1154055056008f201), you need to make a further request using the URL specified in response header "`Operation-Location`".

In following test code, we can find the content is indeed empty.

*Test Code:*

```
var client = new HttpClient();

var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{Subscription_Key_here}");

queryString["mode"] = "Printed";

var uri = "https://{region}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v2.0/recognizeText?" + queryString;

HttpResponseMessage response;

var imagePath = @"D:\xxx\xxx\xxx\testcontent.PNG";

Stream imageStream = File.OpenRead(imagePath);

BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(imageStream);

byte[] byteData = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)imageStream.Length);

using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
{
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var operation_location = response.Headers.GetValues("Operation-Location").FirstOrDefault();

        Console.WriteLine($"Response content is empty({contentString == string.Empty}).\n\rYou should further query the operation status using the URL ({operation_location}) specified in response header.");
    }
}
```

*Test Result:*

[image]

**Note:** Recognize Text API is currently in preview and is only available for English text. As you mentioned, OCR technology in Computer Vision can also help detect text content in an image, and OCR currently supports 25 languages, sometimes we can use OCR as an alternative solution.